# How to export MySQL table in a SQL Server syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to export all of MySQL tables into a SQL Server. How can I generate an export that will automatically create the code to execute into MSSQL?

I have Toad for MySQL if that helps.

Thanks